# Dynamically create controls / objects in C# MonoMac (NSButton, NSLabel)

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, monomac

I'm trying to create an NSButton and an NSLabel in code. I'm able to get it created, but I don't know where I should add it and then wire it up for connections.

I don't want to use XCode (w/ Interface Builder) because these controls would need to be instantiated dynamically.

- Should I add the button in NSApplicationDelegate in the mainWindowController?
- Do I wire it up at the "Window.cs" file?

Can someone point me in the right direction to *dynamically create and wire up* objects in MonoMac / C#?

Thanks in advance,
Yves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing research in Apple docs and Xamarin docs I came up with the following solution. I have no idea if it would work in more complex scenarios, but it's a start.

I have no idea if this is best practice. Either way, I hope this helps other people as well. If I find more information I will update this.

---

### Creating The AppDelegate

#### Some introduction

**Showing the window**

The *AppDelegate* class will create the window and other *NSObject*s (such as NSButton etc..)

First the override the method *FinishedLaunching* - in that method we create the window (*NSWindow*) - see lines at `var window = new NSWindow(...)`. After that there's some boiler plate to

1. Make the window show up starting from the top left `window.CascadeTopLeftFromPoint (new PointF (20, 20));`
2. "Show" the window using `window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (null);`

**Creating the button**

The method `CreateCloseButton()` will generate a button with title, appearance etc.. already set. For an easy guide to pick wich BezelStyle, check out this link: [ http://psionides.eu/2014/10/06/a-guide-to-nsbutton-styles/ ].

**Adding the button to the window**

This section is again inside the method *FinishedLaunching*. Steps taken:

1. Make a rectangle (or `RectangleF`) for the "subview" of the button. This means creating a rectangle where the button lives in. If you would make this too small, the button will not show up fully, but it'll have some missing edges for example. Code is `var closeButtonRect = new RectangleF (8, 8, closeButtonSize.Width, closeButtonSize.Height);`.
2. Next we have to make our button aware that this rectangle is what it will live in by saying: `closeButton.Frame = closeButtonRect;`.
3. Then we add the button (or NSView) to our window. `window.ContentView.AddSubview (closeButton);`.

**Wiring up a click event to the button**

This section is again inside the method *FinishedLaunching*. But it could easily be set up elsewhere. Basically this works as c# events (see snippet below).

```
// Attach an event to the button. When "Activated" / "Clicked" it will close the application.
                closeButton.Activated += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 
                    NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(closeButton);
                };
```

---

### Full Code

#### AppDelegate Class

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoMac.Foundation;
using MonoMac.AppKit;

namespace MonoMacTest02
{
    public class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override void FinishedLaunching (MonoMac.Foundation.NSObject notification)
        {
            // Get the button
            var closeButton = CreateCloseButton ();
            // Get size and create rectangle for the view                 
            var closeButtonSize = closeButton.Frame.Size;
            var closeButtonRect = new RectangleF (8, 8, closeButtonSize.Width, closeButtonSize.Height);
            // Apply the rectangle to the frame
            closeButton.Frame = closeButtonRect;

            // Attach an event to the button. When "Activated" / "Clicked" it will close the application.
            closeButton.Activated += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { 
                NSApplication.SharedApplication.Terminate(closeButton);
            };

            // Creating the NSWindow object
            var window = new NSWindow (
                new RectangleF(0, 0, 400, 300), // Sets the size of the window
                NSWindowStyle.Titled, // Style of the window
                NSBackingStore.Buffered,
                false
            ) {
                // Adding a title
                Title = "MonoMacTest02 (Adding a button)"
            };

            // Add our button to the window
            // AddSubView expects an NSView object. All UI controls are derived from NSView, so we can add the 'closeButton' itself.
            window.ContentView.AddSubview (closeButton);

            window.CascadeTopLeftFromPoint (new PointF (20, 20));
            window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (null);
        }

        // Creating the button
        private NSButton CreateCloseButton() {
            var closeButton = new NSButton ();
            closeButton.Title = "Close";
            closeButton.BezelStyle = NSBezelStyle.Rounded;

            closeButton.SizeToFit ();

            return closeButton;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Program Class (static void Main())

```
using System;
using MonoMac.AppKit;

namespace MonoMacTest02 {
    public class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            NSApplication.Init();

            var application = NSApplication.SharedApplication;
            application.Delegate = new AppDelegate();
            application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

---

All remarks and suggestions are welcome.